# FIRESTORE - How to fetch values of a collection inside a document?

Tags: node.js, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firestore Database, I have a collection **APP**.

It has a document **doc1**.

**doc1** further has a child collection **coll1**.

Consider the following example.

```
let db = firebaseApp.firestore();

db.collection('APP').doc('doc1').get()
  .then(doc => {
    let doc1Data = doc.data();
  });
```

How can I possibly check for a collection in the response. Or when I already know that there is a child collection **coll1**, how can I loop through its documents.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know the collection ids you can use the `listCollectionIds` method to get them all:

```
var firestore = require('firestore.v1beta1');

var client = firestore.v1beta1({
  // optional auth parameters.
});

var formattedParent = client.anyPathPath("[PROJECT]", "[DATABASE]", "[DOCUMENT]", "[ANY_PATH]");

client.listCollectionIds({parent: formattedParent}).then(function(responses){
    var collectionIds = responses[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < collectionIds.length; ++i) {
        // doThingsWith(collectionIds[i])
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

But, it sounds like you already know it's called `col1`, so it's easier - just reference it:

```
db.collection('APP').doc('doc1').collection('col1').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Sounds Interesting. But is there any method on snapshot that lets us know if it has child collections while looping (2nd Code Snippet). Just to keep things easier.

Comment: There is not as it's separate information to what the real-time system is monitoring.

Comment: If you're using `express`, you need to make your routes before. ;)